# Clearing values in excel cells

Tags: vba, excel

Say I know the `RowNumber` beyond which I would like all the cells in my worksheet to be empty and not merged. How can I do that in vba?

Comment: I thought about looking at the last row possible in ms excel and clearing everything from my RowNumber to that that excel row using .Clear but wasnt sure if thats the best way considering different excel formats might have different row limits

Comment: use `Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count` instead hardcoding last row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a typical method to delete all rows **beyond** a given row:

```
Sub RowKiller()
    Dim RowNumber As Long, Strn As String
    RowNumber = 17
    Strn = RowNumber + 1 & ":" & Rows.Count
    Rows(Strn).Delete
End Sub
```